# Monitoring function access

Tags: c#, postal-code

I would like to write a text in a log file every time someone calls a function into my assembly. I know that I should use postsharp but it's too expensive for my purpose.

If there are any other possibilities, please inform me of those.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Monitoring function calls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317560/monitoring-function-calls)

Comment: The other question was closed because I wrong how to ask it.

Comment: @SalvatoreDiFazio Then you should edit and clarify it, not open a duplicate.

Comment: Oky, next time. I voted to delete the previous question.

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I used Spring.Net for the same purpose. Not sure what's the status of that project now, but at the time it was free. You'll be using Aspect Oriented Programming, which should be similar to the way Postsharp works...

This article shows you how you can achieve what you need with Sprint.net: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26726/AOP-Using-Spring-NET-Part-1

Comment: in the answer before I ask how to achieve the goal using the IOC but the question was sign stupid